# Subset dataframe based on click event of plotly chart with another dataframe

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, plotly, dt

I have the `shiny` app below in which I want to click on a bar of the plot and then subset accordingly the table below based on the `Abcd` column of the first dataframe. Before clicking the table will be displayed without being subseted. My intention is not to use the `crosstalk` package but javascript or another possible way like `plotly_click` event.

```
Abcd<-c("A","A","B","B")
Prod<-c(34,56,56,89)
Div<-c("Ent","Ent","App","High")
dcross1<-data.frame(Abcd,Prod,Div)

Countd<-c(45,67,78,56)
dcross2<-data.frame(Div,Abcd,Countd)

library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("daily_store_oos_gg"),
  DTOutput("daily_item_oos_rctble")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$daily_store_oos_gg<-renderPlotly({
     # You need function otherwise data.frame NN is not visible
    ggplot(dcross1,
           aes(x=Abcd,
               y=Prod,
               fill=as.factor(Abcd)
           )) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") 
  
  # Convert to plotly object
  
    ggplotly(daily_store_oos_gg,source="subset")
    })
  output$daily_item_oos_rctble<-renderDT({
    s <- event_data("plotly_click",source = "subset")
    return(DT::datatable(dcross2[dcross2$Abcd==s$x,])) 
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```